# A big space/margin before the tablayout

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tablayout

I've been stuck trying to figure out what and how this space margin happened just before the tab layout. I'm using fragments, and the problem was inside fragment_home.xml. My app are using fragments, navigation drawer, and bottom navigation menu.  I cannot find any related problem with an answer at the internet. Below is the code for home fragments and main activity.java, and I'm sure it could help solving the problem.

The problem is, a space before the tab layout.

[image]

Here is the code for my fragment_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_kids" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_beauty" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_notifications" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- Content Frame -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Home Fragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Lastly, for MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());


        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navDrawer;
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications, R.id.navigation_beauty, R.id.navigation_child)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        boolean open = drawerLayout.isOpen();

        if (id == R.id.new_menu && open == false) {
            // Handle settings menu item click
            drawerLayout.open();
        return true;
        } else {
            drawerLayout.close();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // Handle navigation item clicks here
        if (id == R.id.nav_item1) {
            // Handle item1 click
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item2) {
            // Handle item2 click
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

I have also already tried to change the layout into relative, frame & linear yet nothing changes, all other layout that is using fragments are getting the problem.

I have also tried to remove the navigation drawer & appbar/toolbar menu, thinking it will help yet no.

I haven't tried to configure the home fragment or main activity java for the tab layout.

I have also tried to adjust the tab layout, I made any possible changes to move its location, like adding Y, changing from top to bottom, etc.

Any answers are much really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this margin before the `TabLayout` you have to remove the property `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from the `ConstraintLayout` in your `activity_main.xml` file which adds a padding from the top area in your Activity. By removing this padding all your fragment containers will eliminate this top space.

Comment: Seriously? Just a 1 line of code? That's all?...

Thank you so much dude! That worked!